# Anyone have an idea about testing wireless connection on wireless access point

Tags: testing, simulation, wireless, access-point

I have a wireless access point where they have 50+ wireless client and the connection just blow up in sometime. I think it related to overload on hardware.
So is there anyway to simulate or something like that to test wireless access point in heavy connection from many client, So I can manage to see what configuration is best for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TMnetSim](http://www.tmurgent.com/appv/index.php/resources/tools/177-tmnetsim-quick-and-easy-network-simulation-tool) to simulate delay and package loss.

Comment: The link is showing error "Error establishing a database connection".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any tool but you can restrict number of clients accessing your router from router web page. You can do some hit and trial and see how many clients can access without router getting blown up.